# Prevent Abbrev expansion after certain symbols in Emacs

Tags: emacs, abbreviation

Is there a way to prevent automatic expansion of an abbreviation in the built-in `abbrev-mode` after certain symbols? E.g. I want my abbrev to expand after whitespace, newline, comma etc., but **not** after a dash or underscore.

I know I can hit  <kbd>C-q</kbd> before typing the (say) underscore, but an automatic solution would be much nicer since this occurs for me very often.

There are some abbrev hooks in the manual, but since I am a total beginner with Elisp I don't see an obvious solution...

Thank you very much!

Comment: The built-in abbrev-mode (i.e. the static ones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so a hint of the solution was already in the question itself. This is what works for me:

```
(defun protect-underscore ()
 (interactive)
 (insert "_"))

(defun protect-dash ()
 (interactive)
 (insert "-"))

(defun protect-equal ()
 (interactive)
 (insert "="))

(global-set-key (kbd "_") 'protect-underscore)
(global-set-key (kbd "-") 'protect-dash)
(global-set-key (kbd "=") 'protect-equal)
```

I am sure there has to be a more elegant solution... thanks goes to Magnar.

Answer (score 1):

Make underscore be a word-constituent character for the current mode. From the [Emacs manual, node `Expanding Abbrevs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expanding-Abbrevs.html#Expanding-Abbrevs):

> > [A]ny character that is not a word constituent expands an abbrev, and any word-constituent character can be part of an abbrev.

Use function `modify-syntax-entry` to modify the syntax class of `_`, to make it a word constituent:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")
```

This solution is useful only if it is not otherwise bothersome for `_` to be a word-constituent character.  Do you want `_` to act as if it is a part of a word or not?  That's the first question.